# Remove object from array and combine it with sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I know there are similar questions as mine and I have read them all and used the examples but I'm still not getting what I want.

I have an array which looks like this:

```
[
    {"uniqueid": "1", "count": "2", "product_id": "12331"},
    {"uniqueid": "2", "count": "1", "product_id": "12333"}
]
```

This is all stored using sessionStorage. What I want to do now is get the array and remove the object with the uniqueid 2. From what I've read this should do it, but it doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
var aProducts = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage('products'));
aProducts = _.without(aProducts, _.findWhere(aProducts, {uniqueid: unique_id}));
```

Also tried this:

```
aProducts = $.grep(aProducts, function(o,i) { return o.uniqueid === unique_id; }, true);
```

And this:

```
aProducts = _.reject(aProducts, function(el) { return el.Uniqueid === unique_id; });
```

None of them seem to be working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you check the console for errors and place them here.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. 

@Joseph, I'm not getting any errors at all. When I check the output using console.log(aProducts), I see the original array.

Comment: What type is your `unique_id`? If it's a number, you should either cast it to a string first, or use `==` comparison. Also, in your `_.reject` example, you capitalized `Uniqueid` incorrectly.

Comment: Perfect, I used to toString() method and it worked on the grep and _.reject function. For some reason it doesn't work with the _.without function, but this is good too :)